# Skip html tags when searching for whitespace

Tags: php, html

I have a line of code here and `$post['post']` is a string that may contain html tags:

```
echo mb_strpos(mb_substr($post['post'], 299), " ");
```

I want to find the first occurrence of a whitespace character from the 299th offset of `$post['post']`, but I want to ignore html tags. For example, I want to ignore the whitespace in the following string:

```
<br />
```

How do I ignore the whitespace inside such html tags?

Comment: use `strip_tags` function http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=EN%2Ffunction.strip-tags.php&lang=en&scope=404quickref

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strip_tags` (More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
echo mb_strpos(mb_substr(strip_tags($post['post']), 299), " ");
```

If you want to allow some HTML tags, you can do it as here:

```
echo mb_strpos(mb_substr(strip_tags($post['post'], "<a><b><span>"), 299), " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), you can use the function strip_tags:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

So **in your case**:

```
echo mb_strpos(mb_substr((strip_tags($post['post']), 299)," ");
```